# Multiple Django admin site on same server ,login abnormal

Tags: django, iis, admin

I deploy serveral django web sites on windows with IIS on same server,such as A,B,C.  Each site works,but when I login django admin on site A,the login of django admin on site B and C will logout and each operation need relogin. Browser is  chrome.

I want these sites don't interfere each other. Is there lack of django configuration?

Comment: Do these sites use the same configuration file or use the same application pool?

Comment: No,different application pool.

Comment: You can use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis